# Select additional occurrences of a word in TextMate 2

Tags: editor, textmate, sublimetext2

How can I select additional occurrences of a word in TextMate 2? I do this in Sublime Text 2/3 by pressing Ctrl+D (Windows, Linux) or Cmd+D (macOS).

Comment: Looks like this question should be asked on superuser.com

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Updated answer

As indicated below, ⌃W (Select Word) is the shortcut in the current build.

### Previous answer

Taken from the release notes for r9302:

---

Add two new action methods:

```
findNextAndModifySelection:
findPreviousAndModifySelection:
```

These find the next/previous occurrence of what’s on the find clipboard and selects that, but preserves the existing selection. One could e.g. add this to Keybindings.dict:

```
"@d" = ( "copySelectionToFindPboard:", "findNextAndModifySelection:" );
```

This binding will likely be default in an upcoming build, but bound to ⌃W (Select Word) and scoped to dyn.selection (so only when a word is already selected).

---

You can learn more about key binding files at:

- http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html
- http://blog.macromates.com/2006/multi-stroke-key-bindings/

Comment: Helpful context for `Keybindings.dict`: http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/

Answer (score 3):

There are two macros [here](https://github.com/tbates/textmate.tmbundle/tree/master/Macros) that do what you want.

They are hooked to `^-W` and `shift-^-W` and have a *dyn.selection* context.

This lets `^-W` select the current word as usual, but once a selection exists, it will extend the selection (using TM2's nifty ability to generate multiple selections).

I imagine allan will soon add something like this or better by default, but 'til then, this a a great feature!

Comment: the multi-select powers of ^W were removed, do you know how to quickly get them back?

Comment: Is there a way to make the search for additional instances of the word wrap around, that is, look back to the top of the document (a la ST2)?